# createRecord for one-to-one relationship fails in ember-data RC1 (ember data revision 11)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

`createRecord` never creates the `belongsTo` object.

Is there any work around for creating the child model object in a case where there is such relation `Post-> hasOne -> Comment` and comment is embedded *always* inside the Post.

This works with `Post -> hasMany -> Comments` (as in ember-data-example. Need help, we are stuck with this problem.

```
    App.Test  = DS.Model.extend({
      text: DS.attr('string'),
      contact: DS.belongsTo('App.Contact')
    });
    App.Contact  = DS.Model.extend({
      id: DS.attr('number'),
      phoneNumbers: DS.hasMany('App.PhoneNumber'),
      test: DS.belongsTo('App.Test')
    });
    App.PhoneNumber = DS.Model.extend({
      number:  DS.attr('string'),
      contact: DS.belongsTo('App.Contact')
    });

    App.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    init: function() {
      this._super();

    this.map('App.Contact', {
      phoneNumbers: {embedded: 'always'},
      test: {embedded: 'always'}
    });
   }
});


/* in some controller code */
this.transitionToRoute('contact', this.get('content'));
```

The following line of code works:

```
this.get('content.phoneNumbers').createRecord();
```

The following line of code fails:

```
 this.get('content.test').createRecord();
```

Here  is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <App.Test:ember354:null> has no method 'createRecord'
```

So hasMany works with createRecord but 1:1 fails. Am I doing something wrong ? What must be the right way/is it not possible to do this ?

Comment: @adrien coquio thanks, any clues about the problem ?

Comment: We do not have enough information to properly see what is your problem. Maybe you can try to write a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce the problem ? Or add some of your code sample which will be more explicit ?

Comment: @adrien coquio I hope my edit helps you. Looking for help we are stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `hasMany` relationship is represented with a `DS.ManyArray`. This array is by default empty, but still exposes a `createRecord` method.

A `belongsTo` association is only a reference to a record. It is `null` by default. So you don't have any method to call on it.

In your case you want first to create a record and then assign it to the other record.

```
this.set('test', App.Test.createRecord()); // the controller is a proxy to your model, no need to use content
```

or you can assign the contact to a new `App.Test` record

```
App.Test.createRecord( { contact: this.get('content') } );
```

Comment: We faced more troubles with a deep hierarchy NoSQL backend. There are problems if the object nesting is too deep, we need to make object instantiation to n levels deep. Rather we went with a way, we as off now keep Ember Data DS Objects as our primary interaction with the backend Rails+Mongo with all first level objects (Contact in our example) as custom object with a DS.Trasnforms to reflect them as Ember Objects. For all complex stuff, we operate under Ember Object and we writeback it to Ember data. We were hitting on to lots of problems with sideload and other stuff. But thanks a lot.